# Android string.xml and xmlstarlet

Tags: android, xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

I try to change the app_name in the strings.xml in in a build script, so I need to do this by command line.
I try it with

```
xmlstarlet edit --update "/resources/string[@name='app_name']" --value 'newname' strings.xml
```

but nothing happens...
The xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">name</string>
    <string name="something">name</string>
    ...
</resources>
```

Comment: What precisely do you mean "nothing happens"? What *should* happen is you get the updated XML on stdout.

Comment: I get the unmodified xml on stdout

Comment: works for me, I get `<resources><string name="app_name">newname</string>...` on stdout

Answer (score 1):

You should use '--inplace' argument in order to replace original strings.xml file with the updated one.

```
xmlstarlet edit --inplace --update "/resources/string[@name='app_name']" --value 'newname' strings.xml
```